# How to make custom sql log in symfony 2 and doctrine 2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to add sql logging to work in native WebProfileBundle.
When  I do one default connection in application config, I see the sql
queries in my log. But my application uses many connections to many db
servers, so I can't add all the possible connections to config file.

I create runtime connections, i.e.:

```
$config = array(
        'user' => 'user1',
        'password' => 'pass1',
        'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
        'port' => 3306,
);
$conn = DriverManager::getConnection($config);
```

then I think, should be command something like this

```
$conn->getConfiguration()->getSQLLogger($someLoggerObject);
```

I've  tried  to  solve  this  problem  with  DependencyInjection, took
DoctrineBundle as example. But have no luck.

Any help with live code or link to proper documentation would be great

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my conf:

```
$config = new Configuration;
/** configuration stuff */
$config->setSQLLogger(MyLogger::getInstance());

$connectionOptions = array(
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => DB_USER,
            'password' => DB_PASS,
            'host' => DB_HOST,
            'dbname' => DB_NAME,
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'driverOptions' => array(
                    'charset' => 'utf8'
            )
    );
$em = EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);
```

I use Zend + Doctrine2 and that is in my bootstrap, my logger is a singleton (thats why getInstance). I've never user DriverManager, but i hope this helps.